# I want to sort array in angular that id like 0, 00, 000, 0000, 01, 02 order of top to bottom

Tags: angularjs

I have array like below and I want to organize sorting order for this array in angular js

> [{
>        id :0
>        },{
>        id:000
>        },{
>        id :00
>        },{
>        id:0000
>        },{
>        id:01
>        },{
>        id:03
>       }]

Expected sorting like 0 > 00 > 000 > 0000 in that order of top to bottom

> [{
>        id :0
>        },{
>        id:00
>        },{
>        id :000
>        },{
>        id:0000
>        },{
>        id:01
>        },{
>        id:03
>       }]

Comment: yes is angular(1.x)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an Angular question, it's a JavaScript or Typescript question with two parts. The real question is how you can sort an array treating the values as strings with leading zeroes.

To even *have* leading zeroes in the values they have to be encoded as strings. So this string would not parse as you expect. For that matter JSON is quite snippy about syntax and you *must* also quote property names, so your example won't parse at all.

```
JSON.parse("[{ 'id' :0 },{ 'id':000 },{ 'id' :00 },{ 'id':0000 },{ 'id':01 },{ 'id':03 }]")
```

will (if it parses at all) produce this array of objects:

```
[ { id: 0 }, { id: 0 }, { id: 0 }, { id: 0 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 3 } ]
```

To get it to work the way you want you need to ensure that the values are quoted.

```
JSON.parse("[{ 'id' :'0' },{ 'id':'000' },{ 'id' :'00' },{ 'id':'0000' },{ 'id':'01' },{ 'id':'03' }]")
```

will parse the values as string literals, preserving your leading zeroes. If the values are not quoted, you're screwed and the only way you could possible get this to work is to write your own very non-standard parsing, something I suspect to be well beyond your current skill.

If it *is* quoted, the values are already strings and you only need to sort on the id field. In that case, everything you need to know is documented with worked examples at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Here it is for your case, where we want to sort on a specific member.

```
var foo = JSON.parse("[{ 'id' :'0' },{ 'id':'000' },{ 'id' :'00' },{ 'id':'0000' },{ 'id':'01' },{ 'id':'03' }]");
foo.sort(function(a,b){ return a.id < b.id ? -1 : a.id === b.id ? 0 : 1; });
```